# Background cover attribute not working as expected

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-size

I have made a **background image**, 1366px wide and 768px high, which I want to use as background for the main page of my [website](http://www.clanshnow.com/).

I have each page of my website divided in sections, using the FullPage plugin.
This is the main page so I'm using just the first section.

---

What I've tried so far is adding this `CSS` code to the #first section of my main page:

```
#first{
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background-image: url(images/ClanshnowXmasEventSmall.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Unfortunately the image gets displayed just partially. In fact it's a little shorter than it actually is.

---

I read the **[documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)** for the **background-size** attribute, and at the cover attribute it says:

> Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. **Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area**

So basically how can I make my background-image fit the screen size? Considering the mobile side I think it would be better to fit just the width of it. I'm open for suggestions and help!

Comment: attach the code in code snippet

Comment: It would need too many files, it's better if you press CTRL+U on the website I linked you @vijay

Answer (score -1):

Take a look over here: https://www.google.be/amp/s/css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/amp/?client=safari

Good luck!

Comment: Have already checked that out. In fact I've done just what it says and I got the issue. Thus please avoid posting links into answers because in the future those may not be working anymore and people with this same problem could not find the answer!